# Speedup foreign table query with WHERE field IN () clause

Tags: postgresql, query-optimization

On a database with foreign data wrapper for some tables. Those two queries are really fast

```
select id from local_item_table where **my_condition** 
--> instant answer gives 1,2,3

select * from foreign_table where linked_item_id in (1,2,3) 
--> instant answer
```

whereas this compound query takes ages

```
select * from foreign_table 
where linked_item in (select * from local_item_table where **my_condition**) 
--> very very slow (using inner join is slow too)
```

I guess the second one perform a full scan on foreign table and match records one by one with local data. I want to  optimize this by giving the array of linked_item in the underlying foreign table query. I want to write something that compute the local query and then query the foreign table with the liste of ids. Something like :

```
select * from foreign_table where linked_item in (
    select array_agg(ids) from local_item_table where **my_condition**
)

select * from foreign_table where linked_item = any (
    select array_agg(ids) from local_item_table where **my_condition**
)
```

None of these work but you may see what I'm trying to do. What is the proper syntax ?

Comment: Could you show us the result from EXPLAIN(ANALYZE, VERBOSE, BUFFERS) and your DDL?

Comment: These are simplified version but to give you an idea.
First one on local table > index scan |
Second one on foreign table > Foreign scan |
Compound query > Nested Loop semi join with Foreign scan and materialize of local query

Comment: @bokan Make your simplification concrete.  If it still exhibits the same behavior, then use that concrete instance to address Frank's comment.  We will not get anywhere by having our hands at each other's abstractions.

Comment: @jjanes The question is clear enough providing someone tries to understand it : how to aggregate the ID first then query foreign table with the list of ids in order to avoid nested loop.

Comment: Can you show the INNER JOIN version of your query and the corresponding EXPLAIN ANALYZE ?